# How to get all the indexes of a string without converting that string into an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, string, key

I'm using **PHP 7.2.2**

I want to get all the indexes of a string without converting that string into an array.

Consider below code snippet :

```
<?php
$rootbeer = 'A & W';
$rootbeer[7] = 'J';
?>
```

I want to get all the indexes of a string contained in variable `$rootbeer`.

I want to check whether the original string resent in variable `$roobeer` is padded with white spaces or not after assigning out of range offset to the variable `$rootbeer`.

But while doing so, I don't want to convert the string into an array and then get all the indexes of array elements.

Comment: Please rewrite or explain your following formulations: "*indexes of a string*", "*after assigning out of range offset to the variable*", "*I don't want to convert the string into an array and then get all the indexes*". These sentences/phrases make no sense to me.

Comment: @PhilippMaurer : As the original string has indexes from 0 to 4 only and I assigned a new index 7 which is out of range for the current string under consideration. I want to get all the keys or indexes of this string without converting this string to an array.

Comment: `range(0, strlen($rootbeer) - 1);` ?

Comment: @SerialKisser So basically you want to create the string `"A & W  J"` and find out where the white spaces are? (Get the indices of the white spaces/non white spaces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear to me what you mean by "I want to get all the indexes".

But I'm guessing you mean this:

```
$rootbeer = 'A & W';
$rootbeer[7] = 'J';
$length = strlen($rootbeer);

for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
 echo "Index: ".$i." Contains: ";
var_dump($rootbeer[$i]);
echo "<hr>";
}
```

Will output:
Index: 0 Contains: string(1) "A"

Index: 1 Contains: string(1) " "

Index: 2 Contains: string(1) "&"

Index: 3 Contains: string(1) " "

Index: 4 Contains: string(1) "W"

Index: 5 Contains: string(1) " "

Index: 6 Contains: string(1) " "

Index: 7 Contains: string(1) "J"

Comment: You are wrong. If I write echo $rootbeer[7]; only then J will get printed otherwise not. This means that the indexes 5 and 6 also exist which I want to print out but unfortunately I'm not able to print them out. I want this thing done without converting the string constraining an variable $rootbeer to any array and then using some array function to get all the keys. You should give another try.

Comment: echo $rootbeer[7] will not mean that $rootbeer[5] and $rootbeer[6] exists

Comment: @LelioFaieta : It does mean. They do exist my friend. They contain blank white spaces withing them. Just like indexes 1 and 3 containing blank white spaces within them.

Comment: @SerialKisser You should edit your question because it is completely unclear what you want. An example of how the output should look might be helpful.

Comment: I agree with @simon, anyway, I updated the answer and as you can see, adding a index[7] create also the index[5] and index[6]

Comment: @SerialKisser saying $rootbeer[7] you have just created an array with an explicit key 7 and not the index number 6

Comment: Correct, so if it is not what you need,  I repeat what @simon said: "You should edit your question because it is completely unclear what you want. An example of how the output should look might be helpful"